# Create composite component for f:metadata

Tags: jsf-2, metadata, facelets, composite-component

I want to create a composite component which adds some common meta data to views, like:

```
<viewController:metadata controller="orderController"/>
```

the component:

```
<composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="controller" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

  <f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{cc.attrs.controller.id}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView"
      listener="#{cc.attrs.controller.initConversation}" />
  </f:metadata>

</composite:implementation>
```

i do similar things to add a button bar to all views and it works fine, but it seems its not possible with f:metadata.

Am i right or is there something wrong with my code?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible. The `<f:metadata>` has to go in the view associated with the view ID. See also the [tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/metadata.html) (emphasis mine):

> Declare the metadata facet for this view. This must be a child of the `<f:view>`. **This tag must reside within the top level XHTML file for the given viewId, or in a template client, but not in a template**. The implementation must insure that the direct child of the facet is a `UIPanel`, even if there is only one child of the facet. The implementation must set the id of the `UIPanel` to be the value of the `UIViewRoot.METADATA_FACET_NAME` symbolic constant.

Comment: Hi @BalusC.
I'm looking for something like that too. Is there another way to achieve this kind of component?